# Concatenate list of dataframes that contain timedelta64 datatype fields

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of Pandas dataframes that contain fields with timedelta64 dtype.
When I attempt to concat row-wise using pd.concat, I get this error:

`TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

In fact, even if I run pandas `.info()` method on a dataframe, I get this error. The culprit seems to be some a `np.isfinite` check that the duration type column doesn't pass.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date1': pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T'),
                       'date2': pd.date_range('2017-01-10', periods=5, freq='T')})
df1.loc[:,'duration'] = df1.date2 - df1.date1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date1': pd.date_range('2018-02-24', periods=5, freq='T'),
                       'date2': pd.date_range('2019-01-10', periods=5, freq='T')})
df2.loc[:,'duration'] = df2.date2 - df2.date1

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

You will get this same error if you just run
`~np.isfinite(df1.duration)`

If I have to resort to some alternative methods like merge or join, please keep in mind that the list actually contains an arbitrary number of dataframes.

Comment: Can't reproduce - you can try upgrading `pandas`. Also please note - instead of `df.loc[:, 'duration']` you can just do: `df['duration']`.

Comment: Same as @GrzegorzSkibinski. This code works. Check your version of `pandas` and perhaps `numpy`.

Comment: Yes, old pandas version was the culprit